# How to read specific data(i.e., rows and columns) from a parquet file in gramex formhandler?

Tags: gramex

I want to read a parquet file with only certain columns and certain rows to formhandler in Gramex.

Comment: Can you please explain the use-case a bit in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `city.parquet`, and you want to:

- filter rows where `country` is `Japan`.
- filter columns `lat` and `long`,

**APPROACH #1 - Client-side**: Use this configuration:

```yaml
url:
  data:
    pattern: /data
    handler: FormHandler
    kwargs:
      url: file.parquet
```

Now use the URL `/data?country=Japan&_c=lat&_c=long`. This will filter by the required rows and columns.

**APPROACH #2 - Server side**: Use this configuration

```yaml
url:
  data:
    pattern: /data
    handler: FormHandler
    kwargs:
      url: file.parquet
      function: data[data.country == 'Japan'][['lat', 'long']]
```

Now the URL `/data` returns only the required rows and columns.

**When to use which approach**:

If you want the user or the application to control the rows and columns, use the client-side approach.

If you want to securely share only the required data, use the server-side approach.

Comment: Abhijit, did either of these approaches work, please?